# Unity Problem with Raycasting Masklayers or distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make 2 types of enemies, melees and ranged, so im trying that both have a raycast to the player to know if they can see the player and are enought near, but I have two problems. The first one is that when I check the distance between the enemy and the player is always 0, and the second is that Raycast doesnt print when it should.
Let me explain, Im in front of the enemies and it prints that sees me, but other times not, in the same conditions, so i dont know what im missing.

Here is my code :

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMelee : EnemyBase {
    public int rangoAttack;
    RaycastHit hit;

    int layerMask = 1 << 2;


    void Update () {
        perseguir();
        attackMele();

    }

    void attackMele() {


        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, player.transform.position, layerMask)){         
            print(hit.distance);
        }

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, player.transform.position, Color.red);

    }

}
```

Enemies are on Layer 2

Pd: EnemyBase script just have movement to the player with nav.SetDestination (player.position);

Image of the enemy (cant upload images yet):  https://ibb.co/eq7pMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem** occurs because you don't use `hit` in the code. So `hit.distance = 0`.

**Second problem** occurs because in `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, player.transform.position, layerMask)` you should set direction in 2nd argument (Not endpoint). You can calculate direction by this: `Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - transform.position`.

Try this code:

```
RaycastHit hit;
int layerMask = 1 << 2;
public float maxDistance;

void Update () 
{
    attackMele();
}

void attackMele() 
{
    Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - transform.position;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
        print(hit.distance);

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, player.transform.position, Color.red);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: But why it doesnt print all the time the distance? It stops printing when it wants and i dont get why (Doesnt matter if it sees me or not)

Comment: @AxelVelasco if the distance is greater than `maxDistance`, it doesn't print. Do you check the distance?

Comment: Yeah, i checked saying that it can be like 100, and it doesnt give never a right distance, because always is smaller than 1 (when wants to print, because usually doesnt do it)     Edit: I dont know if matters, but the enemies are moving with a navmesh

Comment: @AxelVelasco Sorry for the delay. Do you use `LayerMask` for enemies or player? And can you share a photo of enemy and player `Inspector` window?

Comment: Edit: Ok, i changed some things and now it sees the character always. I need to check what layer is hitting and that should be enought :)